# How do you create a link to an outlook template from html5 page?

Tags: javascript, php, windows, html, outlook

I want to create a simple link to an outlook **Email Template**. This one links to:

[image: your file was not found]

```html
 <a href="C:\Users\user\Desktop\outlooktemplate.oft">Outlook Email Template</a>
```

Comment: Please explain what do you want to achieve.  Lets suppose you can get this oft file. How do you want to use it further?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```html
<a href="mailto:youremail@outlook.com">Outlook Email Template</a>
```